# What does "liberal's idea of a model" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

What does "no Ameican liberal's idea of a model" mean in the sentence "South Carolina, no American liberal’s idea of a model, has pursued a notably enlightened reform to the sentencing of non-violent offenders"?

Comment: It means that no American liberal would consider South Carolina as a good example to follow.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yes, generally, but the sentence is saying that the SC government's reform is a notable exception that American liberals would support.

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, of course. That's the entire point here. Still, the quoted snippet means what I said.

Comment: "Liberal", of course, is referring to ones political leanings, in this case preferring more social liberties.  (But the terminology is complicated overall.)

Comment: The overall idea here is similar to the saying _even a stopped clock is right twice a day_.  That is, even South Carolina can do something right once in a while.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I agree with you, I just didn't want anyone to get the idea that liberals woud not support the government's actions in this case.

Answer (score 1):

From the idiom **be a/the model of (something)**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/model)

> To be an ideal example or version of something.

In this case:

> Surprisingly, South Carolina, not American liberal’s **idea of a
>   model** state, has pursued a notably enlightened reform to the
>   sentencing of non-violent offenders"